# Delete a cell from UITableView programmatically

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a **UITableView**, when a cell is taped I want to delete it automatically (no editing mode).

When it is tapped I can delete that object/data in the **dataSource**, but then how can I update the TableView, or refresh it so it so it shows the data in the dataSource after I change that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method as it's more efficient than `reloadData` and allows you to animate the deletion.

Answer (score 2):

then you can just do it simply: `[self.tableView reloadData];`